# How do I find the roots of a quartic, without guessing?

Tags: polynomials, roots, quadratics, quartics

I'm given a quartic function to sketch, and one of the things to find is the zeros/x-roots/x-intercepts. After a lot of guessing (and no success) I pulled it up on my trusty TI, to find the roots are all decimals. Is there a way (perhaps similar to the quadratic formula) to find the roots for a quartic? Thanks.

-For reference, the one I have is $f(x) = x^4 - 8x^2 - 7$

Comment: Substitute $u = x^2$ and see what you find.

Comment: For the general case see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function)

Comment: I understood the concept of the "u thing" but wasn't able to make it work. It gave me values, but not the correct ones.

Answer (score 2):

The equation $x^4-8x^2-7=0$  is a quadratic equation in $x^2$. Let $y=x^2$ and solve the equation $y^2-8y-7=0$, using the Quadratic Formula. Now that we know $x^2$, we know $x$.

**Remark:** There *is* a formula for the roots of a [general quartic,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function) due originally to Ferrari. A number of other mathematicians, including Descartes, produced variants. It is not computationally useful.

Comment: I'm quite curious about your statement that Ferrari's method or "formula" in not computationally useful.  I guess I would say it is computationally difficult, for a number of reasons, but not computationally *useless*?  Could you expand?  This is a sincere request, not merely trying to critique your post, which I incidentally upvoted!  I mean, am I missing something?

Comment: All too often, we need to solve an associated cubic that falls under the *casus irreducibilis*. So we need to solve a cubic with real roots whose roots can only be obtained in terms of cube roots of complex numbers, cube roots that can only be found "algebraically" by solving a *casus irreducibilis* cubic. That said, I once made a little consulting money out of the *casus irreducibilis*, trigonometric solution. A user of an early spreadsheet really needed a "formula," not an algorithm.

Comment: Like I said, it's difficult, not *useless*, as evidenced by by your own professional activities around it!